# NLP algorithm to extract part of sentence in language translation

Tags: nlp, nltk, linguistics

I am trying to solve a problem but am not able to find a way other than training the data sets and making a classifier.

**Problem:**

The user says to translate a particular sentence from one language to another. I have the user speech in text part, and need to extract these 3 things from the text:

- Sentence to be translated.
- The language in which its supposed to be translated.
- The origin language.

So, when we humans say, its usually in the form of these examples:

- What is I love you in French from English?
- Can you translate I love you from English to French?
- What is French for I love you in English?

And any other possible way that a person can ask for translation.

I need to extract `I love you`, `French` (the language translated into) and `English` (the language translated from) from the sentence.
The first thing that came to my mind was to use `Regular Expessions`. But I found that it can only be used to detect the language and not the sentence part to be translated.

The other possible solution seems to have the various form of sentence as training data set and train a classifier, but I still feel that this NLP problem can be solved using some algorithm but am not able to get anything.

This seems to be a popular problem, so is there any way it can be done?

Comment: This is not a trivial problem at all. A good starting point would be https://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html

Comment: @PradipPramanick Yeah, I have tried thinking of possible ways to use the extractions, but since there are so many different combinations, I am not able to see any pattern any pattern. That's why the other solution seem to be training with a good data set. But I would like to know if this problem can be solved in the pure algorithmic way without the need of any  training data set.